# Add param to an existing URL in Rails 4 link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In my rails project I am in this URL, result of a search form:

```
http://localhost:3000/buscar?localidad=&page=2&&query=de
```

And I have an (a..z) list to order alphabetically the results. When I press the 'A' button I want to add a parameter to my previous URL, so it'd be like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/buscar?localidad=&page=2&&query=de&start=A
```

But in my 'A' button y have this link_to:

```
= link_to 'A', search_index_path(start: 'A')
```

so the URL is just:

```
http://localhost:3000/buscar?start=A
```

, removing all the previous params I had... :(

How can I do to 'concatenate' the params to the previous params I already had in the URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
= link_to 'A', params.merge(start: 'A')
```

Comment: Ok, in my example it would be just:

= link_to 'A', params.merge(start: 'A')

Thanks!

Comment: @raulchopi - Forgot that link-to accepts hash as well in place of url. :) Will update an answer - thanks for pointing it out.